# can't we write to external sdcard in kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I got below error when i try to run my app which try to store data in sdcard.can't we write to sdcard from android 4.4 ?

Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data

Comment: Use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of a hardcoded path. Also make sure you require this permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score -1):

in 4.4 were some changes with saving on external memory, check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) - new methods

Comment: can you explain bit more.I don't understand.My app works well before android 4.4 .

Comment: for the first: put some code for saving. as @Der Golem said in comment for your question - you should use getExternalFilesDir()